# Find wave equation $u(x,t)$ for $u_0(x)=x$ and $v_0(x)\equiv 0$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

> Let a string with linear density $\rho$  and tension $k$ Its left and right hand ends $ [-\pi,\pi]$ are held fixed at height zero (Maybe not at $t=0$, but it are for $t>0$). 
>   Initial velocity $v_0(x)\equiv 0$ and
>   $u_0(x)= x$. Find $u(x,t)$

What I did

I find by the boundary conditions

\begin{equation} 
u(x,t)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\left[\alpha_j\cos jct +\beta_j\sin jct\right]\sin jx
 \end{equation}
And by the Initial conditions
  \begin{equation} 
u_0(x)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \alpha_j\sin jx\hspace{1.5cm}\text{if}\hspace{0.15cm}x\in(-\pi,\pi)
 \end{equation}
   \begin{equation} 
v_0(x)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \beta_jcj\sin jx \hspace{1cm}\text{if}\hspace{0.15cm}x\in(-\pi,\pi)
 \end{equation}

First I tried to find  the Fourier series for $u_0(x)=x$

$$a_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}x\cos n\; dx=0\hspace{1cm}a_0=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}x \; dx=0$$

$$b_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}x \sin nx \; dx=\frac{2(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$$
So
$$u_0(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\sin(nx)$$

And 
$$u_0(x)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \alpha_j\sin(jx)$$

So $$\alpha_j=\frac{2(-1)^{j+1}}{j}$$

And because $v_0(x)\equiv 0 \Rightarrow\beta_j=0$

$$u(x,t)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{2(-1)^{j+1}}{j}\cos(jct)\sin(jx)$$

Is this correct?

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Commenters, please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.